# Div not resizing below floating element

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where a div is not resizing after being push down by other content. I've attached an example. Click the "Toggle Content" button to see the issue. If you resize the browser the div will snap back to full width. Is there a way to correct this issue?

I've also included a screenshot to show the behavior since it doesn't seem to happen on all browsers. It happens consistently in Safari. When you press the "Toggle Content" button the last div "4)" does not expand unless you resize the browser.

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var display = document.getElementById("two").style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("two").style.display = display;
  document.getElementById("three").style.display = display;
}
```

```css
#float
{
  float:left;
}
#float > img
{
  float:left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.content
{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Toggle Content</button>
<br><br>
<div id="float"><img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201703170823"></div>
<div class="content">1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div id="two" class="content" style="display: none">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div id="three" class="content" style="display: none">3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="content">4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Comment: What browser and version? Maybe I don't understand your issue but I don't see it doing anything I wouldn't expect in Chrome 59 on Mac

Comment: Ok, I guess it might be a Safari bug. I'm using Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8).

Comment: Ah yes. I opened it in Safari and see the issue. Same version, probably a bug. You might be able to work around by resetting the div's width to `auto` in your toggle function

Comment: This is a simpler example but I tested with Chrome in my main project and I still see this issue happens sometimes in that browser too. It always happens in Safari.

Comment: Hmm. Try adding `width:auto` on the `.content` class. That might be enough to prevent most browsers from guessing.

Comment: I tried that but nothing like that worked.

Comment: I am still unclear as to what the issue is, can you provide a screen shot of what you get vs what you are wanting?

Comment: Looks like a browser bug to me. Try wrapping all of your `.content` `divs` in an empty `div`. Fixes the issue for me (safari 9.1.2 on mac).

Comment: @Joseph That worked! Thank you! Can you write this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all of the `content` `div`s in a parent `div`:

```
<div>
    <div class="content">1) Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="two" class="content" style="display: none">2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div id="three" class="content" style="display: none">3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="content">4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</div>
</div>
```

This looks like a browser bug where the moved `div` is not being repainted, possibly because it is not being recognized as changed.

Wrapping the whole group in a parent `div` seems to work around this by triggering a proper resize/repaint of all the children when any of them are changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you ask about the bottom div which takes full width here.

You use the ability of 'overflow: hidden' to ignore the floats rather than clear them. But you wrap each paragraph in a separate div with 'overflow: hidden' and that makes them take as many space as they can, because they set their width independently.

To restrict their width to the first paragraph value you should wrap them in a *one common* container with 'overflow: hidden'. Here's an [example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4akp1e8/2/), I added '.content-wrap' class:

```
.content-wrap
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I think that more popular solution of the problem is to add left padding to the parent of float and then add a negative left margin to the float to move it to the left edge (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4akp1e8/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace margin: 10px; in .content to margin: 10px 10px 10px 310px;

   OR
2. Create new div "#contents" after div "#float" and add it in css "overflow: hidden;" and put in all .content elements

   OR
3. Use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)